# Loop Vectorisation

Tags: python, numpy

I need to vectorise the following loop using Numpy for performance purposes:

```
for example in client_local_dataset:
     X.append(example['image'].numpy())
     Y.append(example['label'].numpy())
x_train = np.array(X)
y_train = np.array(Y)
```

Comment: What's the `dataset`?  What's the individual `example`?  Must be something that has a `numpy` method.  Unless there's a way of applying the `numpy` method to lots of `example` entries, this probably is optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Your code example is incomplete as the definition of `client_local_dataset` is missing. Here is my guess what it is and what you want:

```py
import numpy as np

client_local_dataset = [{"image": "i1", "label": 'a'}, {"image": "i2", "label": 'b'}]

my_vec_fun1 = np.vectorize(lambda elem: elem["image"])
my_vec_fun2 = np.vectorize(lambda elem: elem["label"])

X = my_vec_fun1(client_local_dataset)
Y = my_vec_fun2(client_local_dataset)

print(X, type(X))
print(Y, type(Y))
```

`np.vectorize`d functions can take the whole list `client_local_dataset`as an argument. They return a `numpy` array.

EDIT: Faster would be list comprehension:

```
X = np.array([elem["image"] for elem in client_local_dataset])
```

Comment: But will this improve performance?

Comment: Of course it will. for-loops in Python are very ineffective.

Comment: `np.vectorize` does not promise that kind of performance!

Comment: You are right, I did some test: list comprehension is much faster that np.vectorize. Added that to the answer. Thanks for the hint!